# Want to trigger a Zapier action for each email extracted from a list of emails using Python

Tags: python, zapier

I have a string variable in Zapier that contains multiple emails (a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com, etc.). I need to extract each email and pass it on to the next Zapier action.[I've taken a screen shot of where this appears in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGdSn.png) So a string that has 2 emails would cause the next Zapier action to run twice.

I've tried parsing the string and loading a dictionary, returning the dictionary.

```
emails = []
attendeeList = input_data['attendeeEmails'].split()
for email in attendeeList:
    a = {'Email' : email}
    emails.append(a)
return emails
```

This returns all the emails in a form basically the same as they were submitted - comma separated list or string. (So not multiples). It does cause the next action to run in the Zap, but with multiple emails in the field "Email". Not what I want.

I've also tried just returning each email as I march through the created List.

```
attendeeList = input_data['attendeeEmails'].split()
for email in attendeeList:
    output = {'Email' : email}
```

I haven't seen any output from this one yet. It's taking me about 1/2 hr to see results from any tweaks.

I'm afraid I don't know Python very well - only what I could learn from several hours spent in "Code Academy". So I know enough to be dangerous. But with the passing of variables and purported ability of Zapier to trigger multiple actions from the return of one dictionary, I'm a little overwhelmed. I'm sure it's simple if you know more than me.

My source of the string containing the emails is Google Calendar. And with the 15 min checking cycle it's a long slog to get feedback on what I've done. Any guidance would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

The following one-liner would give you a list of dictionaries from the comma-separated list of emails. Hopefully Zapier would take it from there.

```
[{'Email': email.strip()} for email in input_data['attendeeEmails'].split(',')]
```

Also please be aware you shouldn't have to wait 15 minutes every time. You can just click on re-test when you get to the 'test this step' stage.

Comment: Thank you. Very elegant. Will test soon.

Comment: Hello Kieran. Would you be willing to look at my follow up question I've appended to the original?

Comment: This question is too large now and separate issues should be posted as separate questions @DougChristensen

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have posted a separate question now but I must have done something wrong as there have been zero responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split on a delimiter, in this case a comma.

So your attendeeList would look like this:

```
attendeeList = input_data['attendeeEmails'].split(',')
```

And to remove any extra whitespace, you should then `.strip()` the emails in your loop like this:

```
for email in attendeeList:
    a = {'Email' : email.strip()}
    emails.append(a)
```

Comment: I have an extended capability I'd like to add to this. The method I created does not work. It instead revealed a structure to the data than might call into question my original approach and point the way to covering my 2nd need.

Comment: Hi wpercy, thanks again for your help. Would you be willing to take a look at my followup question I've appended to the original?

Comment: @DougChristensen Hey Doug, I'd be happy to help, but you shouldn't update your question once it has been answered correctly, you should submit a new one. Basically just copy/paste the "Problem #2" and below along with any relevant information from above.

Comment: Thank you for that guidance. I have posted a separate question now but I must have done something wrong as it's been several days and there are zero responses.

Comment: @DougChristensen I took a look at your other question for you, but you should give this answer an upvote and accept it if it worked for you!